# C# Passing a value a new form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I got windows form am trying to pass value from that form to new one, when an button is clicked. using:

```
private void Edit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {

             Edit item = new Edit(int.Parse(listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()));
            item.ShowDialog();

            }
        }
```

When I run the program it doesn't show the form I designed it shows this instead
[image: problem]

But when i change the code to  this:

```
 Edit item = new Edit();
   item.ShowDialog();
```

run it, it display the right thing, but doesn't pass a value to the second form.
[image]

I there a way to pass a value to another form?

Comment: Something odd here. Could you post the code in your form Edit constructor/s and form_load event. And that loop doesn't seem quite right. (You open the same form passing the same index for every selected item)

Answer (score 7):

Add a property

```
Edit item = new Edit();
item.Value = 5;
item.ShowDialog();
```

### EDIT:

You have to define this property to use it. Extend your `Edit` class like that:

```
class Edit {
    ...
    public int Value { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I got this error "Error 1 does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'company.Edit' could be found" what do i do?

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure that your parameterised constructor has `InitiaizeComponent()` in its body. As this function name specifies it initializes components of your form which are company label, textbox and button.

I'll tell you how.

Create a parameterized constructor of edit form. Pass that value into a variable

```
public class Edit
{
    public int val = 0;

    public Edit()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Edit(int a)
    {
        val = a; 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Edit_Load()
    {
      txtbox.Text = val.ToString();
    }
}
```

and call edit from first form like

```
Edit item = new Edit(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: In your own Constructor you forgot to call IntializeComponents().